# Installing Scikit-Learn on Windows

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying to install Scikit-Learn on my windows 8 64-bit computer using:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

and I get the following error,

```
F:\path\python-2.7.10.amd64>pip install -U scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit_learn-0.17.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
  Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.16.1
    Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.16.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scikit-learn-0.16.1
  Rolling back uninstall of scikit-learn
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\path\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "f:\path\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "f:\path\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 748, in install
    requirement.rollback_uninstall()
  File "f:\path\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 747, in rollback_uni
nstall
    self.uninstalled.rollback()
  File "f:\path\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 135, in rollback
    renames(tmp_path, path)
  File "f:\path\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "f:\path\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "f:\path\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "f:\path\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'f:\\path\\python-2.7.10.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\__c
heck_build\\_check_build.pyd'
```

**Note that:
After doing some preliminary googling, I could find that I had to start the CMD as an administrator, which I did, and still came across this error.**

Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through multiple answers, I decided to **uninstall Anaconda** and **re-install** it. That solved the problem.

I also found **Win-Python**, which for some reason, I find **more convenient** than Anaconda.

Thank you. :)